# Reset variables inside a 'foreach' loop

Tags: php

As I have really many variables inside my `foreach` loop, it would be great if I could reset them all at once instead of:

```
 $variable_one = ''; // Reset to: It is blank for each loop
 $variable_two = '';
 ...
 $variable_hundred = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were you and had these number of variables which should be set to some value in a loop, I would use an array instead:

```
$arr = ['first value', 'second value','hundred value'];
```

Then you can access what you want by index in your loop, so instead of using:

```
$variable_one
```

You will use:

```
$arr[0]
```

And now you want to reset them all, so you can use array_map() like this:

```
$arr = array_map(function($val){ return '';}, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have such a high number of variables in your loop, you probably should refactor it to make it simpler. If you are sure that having 100 variables inside a loop is a way to go, you can use the following expression:

```
$variable_one = $variable_two = $variable_hundred = '';
```

This will set each variable to `''` in one *very long* line.

Another option is to [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) all these variables in a single function call:

```
unset($variable_one, $variable_two, $variable_hundred);
```

But this will not set their value to `''`, but unset the variable itself.

Comment: Thanks so far. I calculate with a lot of values from my database and store each of them in a variable before doing so. Not a good way to go in your opinion?

Comment: If you use something like `PDOStatement::execute()`, you can pass it an array of values, and to reset an array you can use a single statement like `$values = []`.